# How to barplot a column with 2 different variables in only one bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-col

I have this df: estudios_intubacion

```
  estudio_completo numero
  <chr>             <int>
1 COMPLETO           2838
2 INCOMPLETO          147
```

And i'm trying to ggplot only one bar/col with the two variables of estudio_completo (COMPLETO and INCOMPLETO) in the x axis and 'n' in the y axis. I have tried with position "stack" and "fill"in many ways but I keep getting two separate bars with no proportions.

```
grafico_intubacion <- ggplot(estudios_intubacion, 
                         aes (x = estudio_completo, fill = estudio_completo))+
                          geom_bar(position = "stack") +
                        labs(title = "Tasa de intubación cecal",
                               x = "Estudio",
                               y = "Cantidad de estudios",
                             fill = "Estudio" ) +
                        scale_fill_manual(values = c("#C7CEEA", "#FF9AA2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
x <- rep("Estudio",2)
y <- c(2838,147)
name <- c("COMPLETO","INCOMPLETO")
df <- data.frame(x,y,name)

grafico_intubacion <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y=y, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  labs(title = "Tasa de intubación cecal",
       x = "Estudio",
       y = "Cantidad de estudios",
       fill = "Estudio" ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#C7CEEA", "#FF9AA2"))

grafico_intubacion
```

You will get this output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!